# how to access a controller function from outside of controller in codeigniter

Tags: ajax, codeigniter

I have a folder (suppose it's name is "test") outside of controller folder which contains a file name "error404.php" and my controller name is "test_controller.php" which has a method name "tst()". error404.php is a view page in where i want to access data from test_controller.php via ajax.

```
<script>
$(document).ready(function(e) {
    $('#search_items_err').keyup(function(e) {
    if($('#search_items_err').val().trim()==''){$('#sugglist').html(''); return false;}
        search_key=$(this).val().trim();

        var data = {
                        search_key: search_key
                    };
                    alert(search_key);
       $.ajax({
                        data: data,
                        type: "post",
                        url: "test_controller/tst",
                        success: function(response) {
                            var options = JSON.parse(response);
                            alert(options);
                        }
                    });
    });
});


</script>


 My tst function is:



public function tst(){
$search_key = $_POST['search_key'];
echo "success";
}
```

But my ajax doesn't work. I suspect that it may contain some problems in the (url: "test_controller/tst",). So how can i solve it? What is the syntax of accessing test_controller's method from error404.php page?How do i access base url?

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at this ajax concept

in your ajax function :

```
url : baseURL+'test_controller/search', //Make sure this url is working properly
data : {'search_key' : search_key},
```

in you test_controller/search

```
public function search()
{
    //generate data and load your view

    $data = "Generated Data array";
    $this->load->view('test_folder/search', $data); //Load your view from application/view/ not from outside the controller

}
```

Comment: I have edited my question a bit. I just want to know what will be the url in ajax?How to get base_url in error404.php? @reignsly

Comment: if your javascript is inside your php file.

`url : '<?echo base_url()?>test_controller/search'`